# Swift CoreStore ordering list monitor issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest, corestore

I have NSManagedObject data model `ExerciseEntity` also I have data mode `MuscleEntity`. I can access muscle object via `exercise.muscle`

I've adde `CoreStore` monitor to observe changes to data model.

```
    typealias ListEntityType = ExerciseEntity
    var monitor = CoreStore.monitorSectionedList(
        From<ListEntityType>()
            .sectionBy(#keyPath(ListEntityType.muscle.name)) { (sectionName) -> String? in
             return "\(String(describing: sectionName)) years old"
            }
            .orderBy(.ascending(\.name))
        )
```

I expect result where I have all sections which is my muscle names and each section has ordered exercises in it like:

```
Abs section
1 exercise abs
2 exercise abs
Arms section
01 exercise arms
02 exercise arms
```

Insead of expected result monitor returns for me swaped result as 01 and 02 string is < 1 and 2 exercise abs string in ascending order:

```
Abs section
01 exercise arms
02 exercise arms
Arms section
1 exercise abs
2 exercise abs
```

I just want this ascending  ordering rule to be applied internally in section, not for entire list.

I have printed monitor:

```
    (lldb) po monitor
    (CoreStore.ListMonitor<Stacked.ExerciseEntity>) (
    .isPendingRefetch = false;
    .numberOfObjects = 140;
    .sections = 16 item(s) [
        0 = "Abs" (
            .numberOfObjects = 13;
            .indexTitle = "Optional("Abs") years old";
        );
        1 = "Arms" (
            .numberOfObjects = 1;
            .indexTitle = "Optional("Arms") years old";
        );
```

As you can see section 0 is Abs and section 1 is arms, ok let's take a look of objects:

```
        print("Section group name: ", monitor.sectionInfo(at: 0).name)
        for e in monitor.objects(in: 0) {
            print("Exercis name", e.name!, " Should connected to section named:", e.muscle!.name!)
        }

        print("Section group name: ", monitor.sectionInfo(at: 1).name)
        for e in monitor.objects(in: 1) {
            print("Exercis name", e.name!, " Should connected to section named:", e.muscle!.name!)
        }
```

If you don't want to read all output you can notice that the first exercise is connected to Arms, but it somehow appeared in the Abs section.

```
Section group name:  Abs
Exercis name 1111  Should connected to section named: Arms
```

Full Output:

```
Section group name:  Abs
Exercis name 1111  Should connected to section named: Arms
Exercis name Ab Crunch Machine  Should connected to section named: Abs
Exercis name Abdominal Rollout  Should connected to section named: Abs
Exercis name Air Bicycles  Should connected to section named: Abs
Exercis name Alternating Dumbbell Curl  Should connected to section named: Arms (Biceps)
Exercis name Arnold Dumbbell Press  Should connected to section named: Shoulders (Anterior Deltoids)
Exercis name Barbell Bench Press  Should connected to section named: Chest
Exercis name Barbell Curl  Should connected to section named: Arms (Biceps)
Exercis name Barbell Deadlift  Should connected to section named: Back
Exercis name Barbell Front Squat  Should connected to section named: Legs (Quadriceps)
Exercis name Barbell Hip Thrust  Should connected to section named: Glutes
Exercis name Barbell Holds  Should connected to section named: Arms (Forearms)
Exercis name Barbell Lunge (In-Place)  Should connected to section named: Legs (Quadriceps)
Section group name:  Arms
Exercis name Barbell Lunge (Reverse)  Should connected to section named: Legs (Quadriceps)
```

Thought as you see all exercises are ordered right by this rules: `.orderBy(.ascending(\.name))`

By I suppose ordering through section.

So Abs should contains only Abs exercise and arms section should contains only arms exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the ListMonitor to `.orderBy(.ascending(\.name))`, so that's exactly what it does alphabetically:

```
01 exercise arms
02 exercise arms
1 exercise abs
2 exercise abs
```

You will need another property to sort on that will respect your section grouping.

Comment: Thanks for answer John, but is this possible to order elements just in the section. Let's say I have a city entity with a property country. Then country is my group (a section) and cities is a list of cities ordered only for this appropriate country. I don't care about how next section will be ordered, but assuming that the next section will be ordered from A-Z, the same like first one.

Comment: or you can simple understand what I mention using this [image](http://www.techotopia.com/images/3/37/Table_view_grouped.jpg) here is cities separated by Staes but in oder ascending name for each section. So let's say I have the same cities with property state. So I want to group them using state names like California or New York and order cities in each section by ascending name

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander You can provide multiple sorting keys: `.orderBy(.ascending(\.state), .ascending(\.name))`

Comment: thanks works for me!!! and as I understood order of these `.ascending(\.state), .ascending(\.name)` matters?  also how can I order it ignoring case, so ignoring uppercase for example, to order elements alphabetically, currently all ABC at the top of list and abc at the bottom,  but it's better to ignore casing when sorting in my case.

Comment: If you want to do a caseInsensitiveCompare you need to create your sortdescriptor yourself and pass in the selector to do so. As far as i can see, there is no shorthand wrapper for this available in corestore

Comment: @MartinM just because of complexity understanding functional programing with generic types and other it's not so easy to do. I am trying to just into code into the pod library and it's hard to understand sometimes how it works(